# Edit PHP command in composer.bat to full PHP path

Tags: composer-php

I've got a problem to replace the `php` command in `composer.bat` with its full path which is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Xampp\php.exe`:

```
@ECHO OFF
php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

I want to look it like that:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\Program Files (x86)\Xampp\php.exe "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

I got a problem with spaces between `Program` and `Files` and between `Files` and `(x86)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got spaces in your path escape it with quotes:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xampp\php.exe" "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```